# Can I set a default namespace route in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am adding an admin namespace with a few controllers, so our stuff can edit contents from the backend.

For example, I have a `Book` model, and a `books_controller` allowing guests browse. Now I am adding an `admin/books_controller`, providing a backend for admins to edit books.

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :books, except: :show
  end
  resources: books, only: [:index, :show]
```

Currently for all the `link_to` and `form_for` in the admin_books_controller views, I need to add the namespace `:admin`  like this:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @post]) do |f| %>
```

(in the normal controller it would be `form_for(@post)`)

It gets a bit repetitive, and I am wondering if I can set it somewhere in the admin controller so all the `link_to` within that controller will route in the admin namespace?

Comment: If you need to do this, maybe something is not right with your code.

Comment: @lzap updated my question. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scope the model under the namespace, that should automatically be reflected in the form generator.

So something like `rails g model admin/book` will generate a book model nested under the admin namespace.

If you then build a form atop that object, something like `form_for Admin::Book.new` this should target any appropriately nested routes, such as:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :books
end
```

I hope this gives some indication of a direction that you can try out.

Best regards.

Comment: thanks, but what I want is to admin normal resources, i.e. there is a Book model already, and I am not sure if creating another Book model would be a good idea.

Comment: I guess you can extend the form builder, and then use that form builder in all your admin pages, but that seems quite a bit more extensive, and less descriptive than simply adding the `:admin` to the form url array :)

Comment: Ohh. Just thought of something. Another way might be to make a helper method, say `form_url`, that takes one argument (the form's object) and returns the array `[:admin, object]`.

Comment: cool, thanks, but I want `link_to` to do the same too. I guess this is not really possible after all.

Comment: You can always extend the `link_to` method, but that's really not best practice. The problem being that in 6 month, when you look at the code, you won't be able to remember why it works. So basically: **You should never monkeypatch**.

Comment: Somehow I just got it now. Using namespaced model is indeed better/easier, and also allows functionality encapsulation. Sorry for such a late "mark as answer"